# rewrite a group template in Jinja2 and ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have a few templates where I need to decorate some server names and I'd like to do this in one line so that I can use the string as a variable.

`{{ group_vars["dbservers"] | WHAT GOES HERE | list }}`

that will take a list like

```
[dbservers]
db-1
db-2
db-3
```

and then in the template I need them like this:

```
{
  servers: [
    "http://db-1:1234", 
    "http://db-2:1234", 
    "http://db-3:1234"
  ] ....
}
```

As of now I am doing something like this:

```
servers: [
{% for h in groups["dbservers"] %}
"http://{{hostvars[h].ansible_fqdn}}:{{ mymagicport}}"
{% if not loop.last %},{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

which I don't love at all. I'd like to be able to store this in a usable way and then just call `config.to_nice_json`

But I can't seem to find the right recipe to inline the value. I have been messing around with the `map` function but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic on SO and should be posted on Code Review instead.

Comment: Besides being off-topic, I don't think anyone would suggest an appropriate filter for your use case. Unless someone wrote a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable with `map` and `regex_replace`:

**hosts**:

```
[db-servers]
db-1 fqdn_fact=db-server-1
db-2 fqdn_fact=db-srv-2
db-3 fqdn_fact=server-3
```

**playbook**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    mymagicport: '1234'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups['db-servers'] | map('regex_replace','(.*)','http://\\1:'+mymagicport) | list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups['db-servers'] | map('extract',hostvars,'fqdn_fact') | map('regex_replace','(.*)','http://\\1:'+mymagicport) | list }}"
```

First task – to work with inventory hostnames, second task – to work with arbitrary fact from `hostvars`.

**result:**

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "http://db-1:1234",
        "http://db-2:1234",
        "http://db-3:1234"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "http://db-server-1:1234",
        "http://db-srv-2:1234",
        "http://server-3:1234"
    ]
}
```